# Do graduate students placed on academic probation recover?

Tags: graduate-school

I just completed my first semester of my master's program in EE, and had a rough time adjusting. In the end I received two B's and C (in a class I should have done better in). I realize now that undergraduate effort won't cut it for these classes.

I have a semester to get my GPA up to a 3.0, and I'm sure that if I put in the effort I can get there, but I'm very worried about my ability to succeed. I had a 3.5 undergrad GPA (hard first couple semesters, but finished real strong once I got the hang of things) with good research experience.

Are there others that have been in this position? Does everyone hit the ground running and get a 4.0 first semester? Or am I doomed and not fit for graduate school?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this. You have a semester to get your GPA to 3.0. Therefore you are almost by definition able to recover (?) In the same vein, if you're doomed and not fit for graduate school you'd have been forced out of the program already. Of course, not everyone gets 4.0 in their first semester. Undergraduate GPA and research experience also ceases to matter in grad school; it's what you do in grad school that matters. Go and get that 3.0 GPA, or quit; it's your choice.

Comment: Your situation, and reaction to it, are very common. Yes, grad school is more challenging than undergrad, because it's selective, so that people who were "top ten percent" in undergrad are ... "average". Part of the point is to not think in those terms, because it is self-defeating and nearly non-sensical. Yes, you have to work harder, and not expect so much gratification in terms of "being the best" or "excelling", because things are starting to become more serious/real. The goal now becomes the work, and preparation for it, not "the game".

Comment: Some can - in my case it's difficult to recover.